# Jenkins "checkout" Step Repository Browser Link wrong

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket-server

I need to use the "checkout" step in my Jenkins Pipeline to generate the Repository Browser Links for my changeset to point to Bitbucket (hosted).

The Source looks like

```
stage('Checkout') {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']],
            userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@myhostedbitbucket/myProject/myRepo.git']],
            browser: [$class: 'BitbucketWeb', repoUrl: 'https://myhostedbitbucket/projects/myProject/repos/myRepo']]
        )
    }
```

There are 3 different kind of Links generated, 2 of them work:

- Revision Link - Points to https://myhostedbitbucket/projects/myProject/repos/myRepo/commits/1642a36f0626c40697c169afd6fb36ffee9ebb27 --> Works as expected
- Diff Link - Points to https://myhostedbitbucket/projects/myProject/repos/myRepo/commits/1642a36f0626c40697c169afd6fb36ffee9ebb27#chg-package/of/java/class.java --> works as expected
- Source Link - Points to https://myhostedbitbucket/projects/myProject/repos/myRepo/history/package/of/java/class.java --> ROUTES TO 404

If I manually replace the "history" in the Link with "browse" the Link works as expected.

I also tried to verify, if the Problem only occurs on a hosted Bitbucket but also bitbucket.org does not have such a "history" Link.

Is this a bug within the Jenkins Checkout step or a misconfiguration on my side?

I have the following Setup:

- Jenkins 2.32
- Git Plugin 3.0.0
- Pipeline Plugin 2.4 (Pipeline SCM Plugin 2.3)
- Atlassian Bitbucket v4.9.1

Comment: Located the hardcoded "history" in git-client Plugin and created a Jira Ticket: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39905

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem seems to be, that "BitbucketWeb" works as expected for bitbucket.org but not for on premise Bitbucket Instances.

The Difference is, that bitbucket.org has a "history" Page, where you can find an overview of the history of a  file.

This Page does not exist at on premise Bitbucket Servers. There you only have an overview Page for the source-File with a dropdown to show and select different Changesets ("history")